# GridView not loading properly?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a album feature in my app that user can take/pic images in each page of album.

Photos that are being picked by user will be copied to a specific folder (that is exclusive to that album) and will be named with the page of that album (0.jpg, 1.jpg etc.).

for displaying better, I added a gridview layout for each album which will adapt all of images from that album folder on sdcard. now My problem is that gridview is not adapting image in a correct way. for example if I have 4 images in that folder with 0.jpg to 3.jpg it will load 1.jpg in the first item, then 3.jpg in second and so on. If I click on any images and go to that specific page (I get page number via `position` int in gridview onclick) it will show the correct photo but not in gridview. for example it will load 2.jpg in position 1 in gridview, but if I click on this it will show 1.jpg in that page).

By the way I tested this on different devices and on some of them this problem is not happening but not all of them and I can't be sure my user device is what.

**Gridview Adapter Class:**

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] filepath;
    private String[] filename;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
        activity = a;
        filepath = fpath;
        filename = fname;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filepath.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView i = new ImageView(activity);
        Bitmap bmp = Helper.decodeFile(filepath[position], activity, 128);
        i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that could cause this. But how about sorting some arrays before you instantiate the adapter? Or let the adapter sort the received arrays.

Comment: @greenapps can you explain more or even an example code in an answer please? thanks.

Comment: Where do you need extra clarification?

Comment: @greenapps "sorting some arrays before you instantiate the adapter? Or let the adapter sort the received arrays."

Comment: Then what is the problem? Don't you know which arrays i'm talking about? Then please say so. Or is there something else?

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little rookie, I can't understand "letting the adapter sort the received arrays" part, which arrays?

Comment: There are only two arrays in your adapter: filepath and filename.

Comment: Oh Yes. and how to sort them?

Comment: Google for "android how to sort a String array". But before you do that you could check if they have to be sorted. Just print the contents in a loop with Log.d(). And further: if you sort both arrays then will they still be in sync? Start earlier: you probably got the content for those arrays using class File for a directory listing?

Comment: I used `Arrays.sort(filepath)` in my activity (not adapter) after getting arrays and problem solved. But is it the best way to sort? My photo names are all numeric and i'm afraid if it's working perfect in two or three digit numbers.

Comment: No problem with digits. All ok. You only get problems if the number of digits is different like 1.jpg and 12.jpg. Then you should use 01.jpg and 12.jpg.

Comment: I'm talknig about this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289863/java-sort-a-string-array-whose-strings-represent-int BTW Thanks Man. If you want You can post your way as an answer and I will accept that for your reputations.

Comment: Well our comments crossed. I gave already the solution to that problem. Or implement a custom sort. (Google for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the code you posted that could cause this. But how about sorting some arrays before you instantiate the adapter? Or let the adapter sort the received arrays.