# Using the AlphanumComparator

Tags: java, comparator, alphanumeric

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to understand how this algorithm works and how I can implement it so that it sorts my ArrayList.

http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * This is an updated version with enhancements made by Daniel Migowski,
 * Andre Bogus, and David Koelle. Updated by David Koelle in 2017.
 *
 * To use this class:
 *   Use the static "sort" method from the java.util.Collections class:
 *   Collections.sort(your list, new AlphanumComparator());
 */
public class AlphanumComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
   private final boolean isDigit(char ch)
{
    return ((ch >= 48) && (ch <= 57));
}

/** Length of string is passed in for improved efficiency (only need to calculate it once) **/
private final String getChunk(String s, int slength, int marker)
{
    StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();
    char c = s.charAt(marker);
    chunk.append(c);
    marker++;
    if (isDigit(c))
    {
        while (marker < slength)
        {
            c = s.charAt(marker);
            if (!isDigit(c))
                break;
            chunk.append(c);
            marker++;
        }
    } else
    {
        while (marker < slength)
        {
            c = s.charAt(marker);
            if (isDigit(c))
                break;
            chunk.append(c);
            marker++;
        }
    }
    return chunk.toString();
}

public int compare(String s1, String s2)
{
    if ((s1 == null) || (s2 == null)) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int thisMarker = 0;
    int thatMarker = 0;
    int s1Length = s1.length();
    int s2Length = s2.length();

    while (thisMarker < s1Length && thatMarker < s2Length)
    {
        String thisChunk = getChunk(s1, s1Length, thisMarker);
        thisMarker += thisChunk.length();

        String thatChunk = getChunk(s2, s2Length, thatMarker);
        thatMarker += thatChunk.length();

        // If both chunks contain numeric characters, sort them numerically
        int result = 0;
        if (isDigit(thisChunk.charAt(0)) && isDigit(thatChunk.charAt(0)))
        {
            // Simple chunk comparison by length.
            int thisChunkLength = thisChunk.length();
            result = thisChunkLength - thatChunk.length();
            // If equal, the first different number counts
            if (result == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < thisChunkLength; i++)
                {
                    result = thisChunk.charAt(i) - thatChunk.charAt(i);
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            result = thisChunk.compareTo(thatChunk);
        }

        if (result != 0)
            return result;
    }

    return s1Length - s2Length;
}

/** 
 * Shows an example of how the comparator works. 
 * Feel free to delete this in your own code!
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("dazzle2", "dazzle10", "dazzle1", "dazzle2.7", "dazzle2.10", "2", "10", "1", "EctoMorph6", "EctoMorph62", "EctoMorph7");
    System.out.println(values.stream().sorted(new AlphanumComparator()).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
}
```

Currently I have a list that contains 
C1, C10, C11, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, 
but I would like it to order it as:
C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11

I'm not quite understanding how to use this algorithm by looking at the example provided. I would really appreciate some help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("C1", "C10", "C11", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9");
    List<String> sorted = values.stream().sorted(new AlphanumComparator()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sorted);
}
```