# Chaining with AlphanumComparator for Java TreeSet

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I'm using `AlphanumComparator` from [Using the AlphanumComparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170839/using-the-alphanumcomparator/47171282#47171282).  I'm having trouble figuring out how to chain additional comparators to it.

I have an object called `NodeInstance`.  I want to sort on 2 fields.  `definitionId` is an enum whose `toString` is an alphanumeric field.  `displayOrder` is an int.

Tried something like this

```
Comparator<NodeInstance> comparator = ((s1, s2) -> new AlphanumComparator()
    .compare(((NodeInstance) s1).getDefinitionId().toString(), ((NodeInstance) s2).getDefinitionId().toString()))
    .thenComparingInt(NodeInstance::getDisplayOrder);
```

but IntelliJ warns me that `Inconvertible types; cannot cast '<lambda parameter>' to NodeInstane`.

I cannot figure out the correct syntax to get this to work.

I'm trying to use this in a `TreeSet`, so ultimately I want to be able to do `new TreeSet<>(comparator);

Comment: That looks like an _ancient_ class that was written before generics existed.  I'm not a generics expert, but it looks like without the type parameter on `AlphanumComparator`, it can't infer the proper types for `s1` and `s2`.  The `AlphanumComparator` comments contain instructions for "upgrading" it to generics, which you should do.

Comment: Sorry, I posted an old link.  I am using the upgraded version.  I updated the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AlphanumComparator` is a regular implementation of the `Comparator` interface, therefore instead of messing with `compare()` inside the lambda, you need to leverage fluent `static` methods of the comparator.

I think you're looking for [`Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor, keyComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)), which expects a function extracting a *sort key* from the argument, and a Comparator which should be used to compare *sort keys*.

Where *key extractor* function would the following lambda expression:

```
(NodeInstance node) -> node.getDefinitionId().toString()
```

And an instance of the `AlphanumComparator` would serve as a *key comparator*.

```
Comparator<NodeInstance> comparator =
    Comparator.comparing(
        (NodeInstance node) -> node.getDefinitionId().toString(),
        new AlphanumComparator()
    )
    .thenComparingInt(NodeInstance::getDisplayOrder);
```

Explicit type in the lambda expression is required to correctly because it can't be correctly inferred based on the *target type* of the aggregated Comparator.

Alternatively, instead of specifying the type in the lambda, you can use a so-called *type-witness* `Comparator.<NodeInstance,String>comparing(node -> ...)`